# TF Agents: How to use batch normalization within the layers of a ActorDistributionNetwork

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am using the TF Agents ActorDistributionNetwork class in a reinforcement problem with ReLU internal activation functions.  Is there a way to use batch normalization between the layers of this network (either before or after the activation)?  Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/v0.9.0/tf_agents/networks/actor_distribution_network.py#L57-L198), I don't believe this happens by default.

This question originally refers to v0.90 of [TF Agents](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents).

Comment: I am facing a similar situation: I would like to add BatchNormalization to a QNetwork. It is not implemented as of now, but it would no be hard to add, in principle, to the base `EncodingNetwork` class, modifying the code of `tf_agents/networks/encoding_network.py`. When done, I can ping back with an answer.